# How to insert data into a table containing one single column?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python and MySQL and have an issue inserting data if my table has one single column (actually one auto-incremented id and a column).

I tried several syntaxes, "playing" with quotes and parenthesis, several ways to implement execute() method, but nothing worked.

Here is my statement :

```
import mysql.connector
db_name = "purbeurre"
list_categories = ['Drinks', 'Meat', 'Bread']
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='toto', password='toto', host='123.456.0.78')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE {}".format(db_name))
insert_categories = ("INSERT INTO Categories (name) VALUES (%s)")
cursor.executemany(insert_categories, list_categories)
```

The error is : "ValueError: Could not process parameters"

If I add a column, the statement becomes this one and works fine :

```
import mysql.connector
db_name = "purbeurre"
list_categories = [('Drinks', 'Liquid products'), ('Meat', 'All kind of meat', ('Bread', 'Bakery products')]
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='toto', password='toto', host='123.456.0.78')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE {}".format(db_name))
insert_categories = ("INSERT INTO Categories (name, description) VALUES (%s)")
cursor.executemany(insert_categories, list_categories)
```

As you can see, the only difference is the number of columns.

Any idea of what happens?

Comment: With INSERT queries, you are required to supply values for every column that does not have a default; if you want to be able to insert only `name` values, you must alter your table to have a default value (typically an empty string or null) for your `description` field.

Comment: Hello, thakns for the reply.
I did not mentioned it, but the table has only the inserted column ('name' only in the first case, both 'name' and 'description' in the second one

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe something like this is needed? `list_categories = [('Drinks'), ('Meat'), ('Bread')]`... or `(,'Drinks')`? I seem to recall seeing some language around here were the parameters needed leading commas.

Comment: This something I tested and it does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the answer.

The list of data was not correctly defined, here is the correct syntax :

```
list_categories = [('Drinks',), ('Meat',), ('Bread',)]
```

Beware of the comma *before* the parenthesis is closed to ensure each element in the list are tuples.